# Problem in scraping data in non-english character sites [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the number of post within hashtag, it works perfect with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hkig')
source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

post = soup.find('span', class_='g47SY ').text
print(post)
```

However, if I change the tag to non-english characters, it crashes, what is the cause and how to solve it?

Following script will give out errors:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import datetime    

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/モデル')
source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

post = soup.find('span', class_='g47SY ').text
print(post)
```

EDITED:

The error I got is as follow: Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/temp.py", line 12, in 
>       post = soup.find('span', class_='g47SY ').text AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

It appears that the beautifulsoup cannot find anything in `'span', class_='g47SY '` so it give out such error, so back to my question why is it unable to find it? I checked the number of post's element indicating it is still `<span class="g47SY ">6,262,389</span>`, perhaps its about the utf-8 ascii encoding issues?

Comment: Could you please give us the error you receive

Comment: attribute error as I believe the soup unable to find any element at all.. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever scraping data using selenium consider to add `sleep` in most cases it takes time to load page and hence entire source code of page not caught up. for reference look at workable code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time        #note this line

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/モデル')
time.sleep(8)                                          #note this as well moreover it should be after get method 
source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup)

post = soup.find('span', class_='g47SY ').text
print(post)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to wait using `WebDriverWait` until the element with class name `g47SY` located, and it better to not use BeautifulSoup if using Selenium.

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/モデル')
post = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_class_name('g47SY')
)
print(post.text)
```